# Tinymce not working in IE from server

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce

I've a Rails application that uses Tinymce to allow users write posts from many forms.

It works perfect in firefox and chrome but it doesn't work in IE. I can assume that but the problem is... it is working perfectly in IE when I try it in my dev enviroment.

When I try to use those forms from server I get these errors:

```
    SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 'parentElement',
tiny_mce.js?1364308119 line 1 character 41026
```

I know this is not too specific but I hope somebody faced this problem before 8-)

Tinymce version is 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the tinymce settings? You  might have to update your tinymce.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with? Have you checked that the browser isn't dropping into compatibility mode or quirks mode?

Comment: I'm trying it in IE 9 and no, it's not in compatibility mode :(

Comment: I think there is an plugin or a method in the editor calling a the parentELement function of an element that doesn't have this function. I'm developing a plugin for CKEditor at the moment and you have to check this always very well. Did you add anything special to the editor what may have caused this?

Comment: It's really strange, I didn't change anything and it was working until yesterday...